# Can you use env variables in node child_process.spawn()?

Tags: node.js, environment-variables, child-process, spawn

This works

```
cp.exec('echo $TEST', { env: { TEST: 'Hello World!'}) // Hello World"
```

But this doesn't

```
cp.spawn('echo', ['$TEST'], { env: { TEST: 'Hello World!' } } ) // $TEST
```

Is there a way to use env vars in spawn args?

Answer (score 0):

```
const cp = require('child_process');

// make sure you have property shell set to true

const cmd = cp.spawn('echo', ['$TEST'], { env: { TEST: 'Hello World!' }, 
shell: true } );

cmd.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(data.toString());
});
```